# PHP: Cannot exec() wkhtmltopdf: "sh: /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf: Permission denied"

Tags: php, linux, permissions, exec, wkhtmltopdf

I am not really into unix and that's why this thing is kind of weird for me.

The OS is CentOS 6.

I read nearly all topics concerning wkhtmltopdf, but my problem still exists. Actually it's not a wkhtmltopdf problem, but a permission problem.
To sum it up: wkhtmltopdf works in the command line, but not with php exec().
But wget works fine with php exec():

I can execute wkhtmltopdf in the command line, works fine:
`/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf "test.de" "/var/www/html/test/test.pdf" 2>&1`

I can execute wget with php, works fine:
`exec('/usr/bin/wget -O /var/www/html/test/test123.txt "test.de" 2>&1', $output, $return_var);`

But I can NOT execute wkhtmltopdf with php:
`exec('/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf "test.de" "/var/www/html/test/test.pdf" 2>&1', $output, $return_var);`

**this leads to "sh: /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf: Permission denied"**

I checked /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf and compared it to /usr/bin/wget.
The permissions are the same: rwxr-xr-x or 0755
Even if I set chmod of /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf to 777 and set the owner to apache, the error is still the same.

Perhaps it's a matter of yum?!
Becauce I installed wget through yum and wkhtmltopdf not. That is the only difference I can think of.

I installed wkhtmltopdf with the following:

`tar -vxjf wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-static-amd64.tar.bz2

mv wkhtmltopdf-amd64 /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf

chmod +x /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf`

Or could it be a problem with SELinux? I don't know very much about it, but I read through my research that "httpd_ssi_exec" and "httpd_execmem" might help and I put both to "yes", but the permission denied issue still exists.

So I wonder why does wget work with php and wkhtmltopdf does not?
Hopefully someone can help me out and I can stop getting mad on this ;)

best regards,
Alex

P.S.: test.de is http://test.de in my scripts, but I am not allowed to post more than two links.

Comment: how were you able to solve this? I'm facing the same issue, and you're right; we should not disable the SELinux. This is a major issue when it comes to being on shared directory. My case is different: 
i am a secondary user on a VPS, with limited permissions. via command line the script works flawlessly

Answer (score 1):

Even though permission is `777` the command getting executed as www user.There will be lot of limitation since www  has very low privilege levels.So use [setuid File Permission](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-bsd-linux-setuid-file/)

setuid means set user ID upon execution. If setuid bit turned on a file, user executing that executable file gets the permissions of the individual or group that owns the file.Hence you can execute that command as root/high privileged user.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but if I set "chmod u+s /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf", it does not have an effect. It is still permission denied.
But I found out, that SELinux prevents it. If I set Enforce-Mode to permissive, then I can create a PDF with wkhtmltopdf.
But I don't want to disable SELinux..

Comment: Another solution is using `Binary wrapper` . Again it needs `suid`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
exec('/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf --print-media-type index.html termo590.pdf 2>&1');
```

Comment: It's return error - Array ( [0] => sh: /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf: Permission denied ) 126

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to disable `SELinux` another method is to use a cron to run this command.`/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf "test.de" "/var/www/html/test/test.pdf" 2>&1`

1)write argument name to a file from your php program.

```
 $Handle = fopen("myfile", 'w');
 fwrite($Handle, "test.de");
 fclose($Handle);
```

2) Create a bash script to read that argument name and convert it to  pdf.

```
#!/bin/sh
arg=$(head -n 1 myfile)   
/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf arg "/var/www/html/test/test.pdf" 2>&1
```

save it as pdf_converter.sh

```
chmod +x pdf_converter.sh
```

3) Configure the script in crontab

`crontab -e` and paste this

```
* * * * * pdf_converter.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Having struggled with the Permission Denied problem I finally cracked it so for anyone else having this issue:

Apache's shell user (www-data) as default can only access files within var/www/

The Shell user simply doesn't have permission to run wkhtmltopdf in it's default directory (usr/local/bin in my case) using exec().

My workaround was simply to copy and paste the wkhtmltopdf from /usr/local/bin to /var/www/bin (I created the bin folder) and targeted that file in my exec

```
exec('/var/www/bin/wkhtmltopdf file.htm testfile.pdf');
```

Boom! PDF's.

Now this may not be safest practise (I don't know if there are security implications to having a bin folder in the var/www directory) but I my case it doesn't matter as this is a test server and for anyone just wanted to verify their other code is working it should at least generate you a test.pdf